# Simple definition of a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, positive-definite

Aside from what it is written in the books about the definition of a positive definite matrix, can anyone explain it in a more earthly method?

Comment: Many authors restrict the use of *positive definite* to symmetric real matrices or Hermitian complex matrices.  You should clarify whether you would include this restriction in requesting an explanation.

Comment: Good point! However,  I'm not a mathematician, but an engineering student.So, I have no idea how to clarify this.

Comment: I will suggest that you, as the one asking this Question, are the authority on what you want to know.  The engineering literature surely has applications that feature symmetric matrices, and I would start there.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to think about it is using eigenvalues.  Remember that an eigenvector of the matrix $A$ is a vector $v$ such that

$$
Av = \lambda v
$$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$ (assuming real vector spaces and not complex).  This says that when you act on $v$ with the matrix $A$, $v$ is just scaled by a constant factor. This number can be positive, negative, or zero.  If it's positive, the vector is scaled but not reflected.  If it's negative, it's scaled *and* flipped.  If it's zero, the vector is in the null space, so it gets sent to zero.  The point of a positive definite matrix is that it scales all its eigenvectors positively, and doesn't flip them or send them to zero.  This also means that orientations are preserved, i.e. the matrix only stretches and compresses things without flipping them.

Edit: Just for completeness, let's also talk about the standard definition.  A matrix $A$ is positive definite if $\langle x,Ax\rangle = x^TAx>0$ for every $x$.  This is exactly the "orientation preserving" property: if you think about the inner product/dot product as giving you the cosine of the "angle" between vectors, saying that the dot product of $x$ and $Ax$ is positive means this angle $\theta$ satisfies

$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}
$$   Intuitively, this means that the two vectors are on the same side of the hyperplane $x^\perp$ defined by $x$, see this picture:

[image]

A positive definite matrix will have this property for *all* vectors $x$.

Comment: Is it possible to look at a matrix and figure out if it is positive definite without considering the eigenvalues?

Comment: No, but if you compute an LDLT (or LU) decomposition and all diagonal entries of D (resp. U) are positive, then the matrix is positive definite. This of course only works if the matrix is symmetric to begin with.

Comment: OK. Is it possible to explain positive definite without referring to eigenvalues?

Comment: @Arbo94 It is, but I would argue that the other characterizations are less intuitive. (The most common alternative characterization is through the bilinear form induced by the matrix.)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of Dk>0 for all leading principal minors and positive semi-definite is Dk>=0 for all leading principal minors.